# Set multiple field terminations for csv file

Tags: php, mysql

I have csv file which contains the row as follows

HP 3 Log;"09.12.2019 12:54:50";24;

This record is in one cell. I want to upload it in database. When i terminate it on ; it is inserted like below

''''''''Col1''''''|''''''''''''''''''''''Col2'''''''''''''''''''''''|Col3|

"HP 3 Log   |""09.12.2019 12:54:50""|  24 |

When i terminate it on " it gives result like

''''''''Col1''''''|''''''''''''''''''''''Col2'''''''''''''''''''''''|Col3|

"HP 3 Log | | |

```
<?php
$table = "data";
$cons= mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root","","nestle_karachi") or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_options($cons, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
mysqli_query($cons, '
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv'
        INTO TABLE '.$table.'
        FIELDS TERMINATED by \'"\'
        LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
')or die(mysql_error());
```

I want these three values inserted in separate column without any special character.

Desired Output will look  like this

''''''''Col1''''''|''''''''''''''''''''''Col2'''''''''''''''''|Col3|

"HP 3 Log |09.12.2019 12:54:50 | 24|

Your kind help is needed.

Comment: Show the final state which you NEED for shown source row.

Comment: People often talk about _normalizing_ database data, but this advice transcends into other structures.  If you cannot normailze your incoming data, then I think you might try escaping all double-quotes and double quote wrapping all column values in your data before trying to parse it.  Do you think you can manage that?

Comment: @mickmackusa I have millions of record in my csv file. If i normalize my data and then insert it. It takes a lot of time.

Comment: @Akina i have edited my question. Kindly have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have csv file which contains the row as follows
>
> ```
> HP 3 Log;"09.12.2019 12:54:50";24;
> ```
>
> Desired Output will look like this
>
> ```
> HP 3 Log |09.12.2019 12:54:50 | 24|
> ```

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.ext'
INTO TABLE tablename 
FIELDS TERMINATED by ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(col1, @col2, col3)
SET col2 = TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM @col2);
```

or

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.ext'
INTO TABLE tablename 
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
FIELDS TERMINATED by ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(col1, col2, col3);
```

PS. If (due to `;` char after the last field value in CSV) server will fail with a message that the amount of fields do not match the amount of values, then add dummy variable at the end of fields list (`(col1, @col2, col3, @dummy)` or `(col1, col2, col3, @dummy)` respectively).

Comment: what if i want to change the col2 into this format 2019.12.09 12:54:50. can you help me with this

Comment: @MariaAbdullah *what if i want to change the col2 into this format 2019.12.09 12:54:50* Do it in SELECT, not during loading data. Distinguish between data storing and data displaying - your words belongs to the last one only.

Comment: i have input data in this 2019-12-09 12:54:50 format. That is the reason i want to update it according to that

Comment: @MariaAbdullah *i have input data in this 2019-12-09 12:54:50 format* **NO!** The data is converted into inner binary format used for datetime storing, where there is no spaces, dashes and colons. When you select data server performs back-convertion into readable format - this is a point where you may alter default output format with the format which you need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `preg_split()` ? Give it a regular expression to use as each of your separators, e.g., '/[;"]/'. That should give you an array like:

```
HP 3 Log
null
09.12.2019 12:54:50
null
24
null
```

Thereafter you can place the desired array cells into the appropriate columns.

You can also pass it the "PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY" flag, and empty columns should be left out.

[PHP Manual page for "preg_split"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Comment: i cannot split it before because normal insert takes a huge time. My csv files has million of records in it. That is the reason i choose the option of load inline.